# Error in summary(deviceprefs) : object 'deviceprefs' not found

Tags: r

I am taking a class and working on a homework assignment, however, I am pretty stuck already in the very beginning, unable to execute any commands except read the file. The .R file and .csv file are in the same directory, project. I am new to R and so far haven't figured out what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate advice on how to move forward. I also got some warning messages when I first loaded R, please see the end of this post. Thank you in advance!

RStudio
Version 1.1.419 
Mac OS 10.12.6

```
deviceperfs = read.csv ("deviceprefs.csv")
View(deviceprefs)
deviceprefs$Subject = factor(deviceprefs$Subject)  # convert to nominal factor
summary(deviceprefs)
```

During startup - Warning messages:

> 1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"  2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed,
>   using "C"  3: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C"  4: Setting
>   LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C"  5: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using
>   "C"

Comment: That warning message almost seems unrelated to your code. What exactly is the problem you are trying to fix? Are you just concerned about that error message? (I assume it appears before you run any code?) Sounds like you might have your computer set to some interesting locale, perhaps some language setting other than US English (which shouldn't be a problem but that would be useful info). Did you install RStudio yourself on your own computer?

Comment: Thank you for writing MrFlick. I installed R and afterward Rstudio, in the recommended order. My assignment is to answer a few questions, based on the information I have from a user test of proportions, a csv file. To get the answers I created an R file in Rstudio, in order to run a few tests such as a chi square for example. The problem I have is that although the scv and the r file are in the same directory I am getting the object not found error for the csv file... and don't understand why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up reinstalling everything, and it all works now.